# What does "Forward reference extends over definition of value" mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

I keep getting

```
Forward reference extends over definition of value a
```

error while trying to compile my application (inside SBT).

`a` is just `val a = ""`, the error is triggered by accessing a particular parameter (of the function) right before `a` definition. The parameter is of a simple case class type with all three fields of `Option[...]` type (2 of `Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]` and 1 of Option of an enumeration value).

What can "Forward reference extends over definition of value" mean at all and what can be the ways to fight it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on your scalac version, there have been bugs where synthetic methods cause this error.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6278

Illustration, imagine f is generated:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    class NotUsed {val x = f}
    val dummy = false
    def f = true
  }
}
```

Case classes, default arguments and implicit classes involve synthetics.

In the example code from that ticket (which has been fixed), you can break the ok method by moving the implicit to the end of the function:

```
object tiny {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    ok(); nope()
  }
  def ok() {
    class Foo(val i: Int) {
      def foo[A](body: =>A): A = body
    }
    implicit def toFoo(i: Int): Foo = new Foo(i)

    val k = 1
    k foo println("k?")
    val j = 2
  }
  def nope() {
    implicit class Foo(val i: Int) {
      def foo[A](body: =>A): A = body
    }

    val k = 1
    k foo println("k?")
    //lazy
    val j = 2
  }
}
```

> what can be the ways to fight it?

As implied by the comment in the code, making the definition lazy is a workaround.

Illustration 2, imagine the function is so long that you don't notice the naming problem:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    class NotUsed {val xs = args}
    val dummy = false
    // oops, shadows the parameter
    def args = Seq("a","b","c")
  }
}
```

Comment: "Affects Version/s: Unreleased-2.10.x, Fix Version/s: Unreleased-2.10.x" - it says. Do I understand correct that the bug is not fixed in any released version, even in 2.10RC2?

Comment: Indeed. I've just tried 2.10RC2 and the trouble is still there... :-(

Comment: I have even made the class a bare class (not a case class) and removed all parameters defaults from it but I still get the error. My case is much simpler - I just try to access a method parameter and it triggers the error. I still can't get how is this particular parameter of any special.

Comment: Why not paste the sample so we can see in particular?  It can also help to use -Xprint:typer (or sometimes a phase after typer).

Comment: I have found the actual problem cause (thanks to IntelliJ Idea showing a value declaration when you hold Ctrl and hover mouse over the value usage)! A val with the same name (like the function parameter) was declared later in the same function. So it's not the complier bug, it's a bug of mine.

Comment: Ha.  Crowd-sourcing it on SO would have been faster than IntelliJ. :)

Comment: Do you mind adding something like "The problem can be also caused by the same-name (as the function argument) value declared later in the function code so that the argument gets hidden being replaced with a value which is not actually accessible." into the answer body to make it more complete?

Answer (score 54):

The error message means that you have a forward reference to a method, i.e. you're calling a method before you define it, and that the definition of the value `x` appears between that forward reference and the definition of the method. It is only legal to have forward references if there are no value definition between the reference and the referred method definiton.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a valid forward reference?

Comment: magic, i rearranged my method and the compilation error vanished

Answer (score 19):

Basically it's a bug.

The fix is to declare a method before calling it. I don't know why.

```
def a(input: String){

}

val k = a("ravi")
```

Comment: Or make the value lazy

Answer (score 10):

If it is referenced somewhere and scalac is confused with the sequence, making it lazy could do the trick

I guess it might be to late for an answer, and since I cannot see what you are actually trying to do I am not sure if that solves it though.

Answer (score 2):

An example for the answer given by sepp2k

```
object ForwardReferenceTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    test
    val x = 1
    def test = println("hi")
  }
}
```

you will get error

```
Error:(7, 5) forward reference extends over definition of value x
    test
    ^
```

the function `test` is defined after the call and there is a value definition of `x` in between. Removing/Moving `val x` definition will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The message means that at run time scala was not able to find the reference of the method that is called in your method.
This usually happens when you try to cal a method and the implementation of the called method is after the calling method.

like for ex:

```
implicit val userDetails: Reads[UserDetails] = (
          (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
            (JsPath \ "providers").read[List[Provider]]
          )(UserDetails.apply _) 

implicit val providers: Reads[Provider] = (
          (JsPath \ "providerName").read[String] and
            (JsPath \ "providerUserId").read[String] and
            (JsPath \ "authtoken").read[String]
          )(Provider.apply _)
```

and the correct way to it.

```
implicit val providers: Reads[Provider] = (
      (JsPath \ "providerName").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "providerUserId").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "authtoken").read[String]
      )(Provider.apply _)

     implicit val userDetails: Reads[UserDetails] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "providers").read[List[Provider]]
      )(UserDetails.apply _)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should check your imports.
It must be importing variable name from the import,
The variable name must be used in some library which is imported to your code.
Remove the import.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to move val definition after the implicit val definition, not clear why. Method that was assigned to the val definition was actually defined before the methd where it was actually called.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when we refer to a variable before it is defined. As the Error states it is Forward Reference.