# Where can I download an SBT 0.13 snapshot package?

Tags: scala, sbt

Being [stuck with a scala 2.9 compiler bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328502/what-does-forward-reference-extends-over-definition-of-value-mean-in-scala) I've decided to try moving to Scala 2.10 RC. As a part of the switch I was trying to install SBT 0.13 snapshot.

The [official web page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0-SNAPSHOT/docs/Getting-Started/Setup) lists a broken link:

```
http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt//0.13.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt.tgz
```

There is nothing about 0.13 in the directory, the link gives Error 404.

Any ideas about where to get the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't wont to compile them on your own, try these:
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/

Comment: Yep. I've just found that in some seconds before you've posted the answer. I hope that is going to work.