# forward reference extends over definition of variable

Tags: scala

In my Test.scala, I defined a Trait and Object for incrementing a number first. Note that I'm using part of the RNG code based on the "Random Number Generator" lesson in [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/).

```
trait NumberInc {
  def currentInt: Int
  def nextInt: (Int, NumberInc)
}

object NumberInc {
  def simple(seed: Int): NumberInc = new NumberInc {
    def currentInt: Int = seed
    def nextInt: (Int, NumberInc) = (seed + 1, simple(seed + 1))
  }
}
```

Then, within my "Test" object's foo() method, I perform the following logic:

```
def foo() { 

  var numberInc = NumberInc.simple(0)

  def bar() = { 
     baz(numberInc.currentInt)
     var (_, numberInc) = numberInc.nextInt /* Error Line */

  }

}
```

But I'm getting this error on the above error line.

`[error] forward reference extends over definition of variable numberInc`

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328614/409976) to be helpful, but I'm not sure how it applies to my above code.

Comment: What is the method `baz`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the method `numberInc.nextInt` it is not referencing the `NumberInc` instance defined a few lines above. It is trying to do a recursive definition since you used the same name for the new variable. If you delete the whole line `var numberInc = NumberInc.simple(0)` you get the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by `you used the same name for the new variable`?  Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue and use `numberInc` as a **var**?

Comment: Just change the line to `var (_, numberInc2) = numberInc.nextInt` for example.

Comment: But, I'll be calling `bar()` multiple times, so I want to use the **current** NumberInc object. Using `(_, numberInc2) = numberInc.nextInt` won't let me re-assign the `numberInc` to the next NumberInc obj, right?

Comment: Well maybe return the next `NumberInc` from `bar`? And then assign `numberInc` to the result of `bar`...Hard to say just based on pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a new variable with the name numberInc instead of changing the old one.
Here is one way to fix that.

```
trait NumberInc {
  def currentInt: Int
  def nextInt: NumberInc
}

object NumberInc {
  def simple(seed: Int): NumberInc = new NumberInc {
    def currentInt: Int = seed
    def nextInt: NumberInc = simple(seed + 1)
  }
}

def foo() { 
  var numberInc = NumberInc.simple(0)

  def bar() = { 
     baz(numberInc.currentInt)
     numberInc = numberInc.nextInt
  }
}
```

But you could also use an iterable instead.

```
def foo() { 
  var iter = Iterator.from(0).toIterable

  def bar() = { 
     baz(iter.head)
     iter = iter.tail
  }
}
```